# Where is located data folder in docker-compose for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, volumes

I would like to deploy my instance of wordpress using docker compose.

I have docker-compose code:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     volumes:
      - ./data-docker/wordpress:/data
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: host.docker.internal:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

I would like to have some "wordpress" folder contains data (images, etc) on my local machine to be able make a backup of current data. I tried to use `./data-docker/wordpress:/data` but this folder is still empty.

Where are for example uploaded images stored? And how can I backup it?

I know that there is also mysql - it is backuped separately.

Answer (score 0):

According to wordpress docker documentation the following should work:

```yaml
...
    volumes:
        - ./data-docker/wordpress:/var/www/html
...
```